# How to call two functions with same name?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I installed 2 NPM packages and they both have a random(); function
how do I specify from which npm package am i calling the random method

here's my code:

```
import { random } from 'superheroes';
import { random } from 'supervillains';

console.log(random());
console.log(random());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [import alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```js
import { random as randomSuperheroes } from 'superheroes';
import { random as randomSupervillains } from 'supervillains';

// You can call it using the alias name

console.log(randomSuperheroes()); // superheroes
console.log(randomSupervillains()); // supervillains
```

Answer (score 2):

You could supply an alias to (one of) the imports, like so:

```js
import {random as alias} from 'supervillains';
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but how do I call it now ?

Comment: By using the name of the alias, which in my example is alias, but you could call it anything you want.